# PL/SQL Сохранение нескольких записей SELECT в процедуре

Tags: oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте!
Техническое задание:
- Считать в процедуре из таблицы заказов записи о каждом заказе.
- Пробежаться по каждому заказу. И сравнить итоговую стоимость с актуальной стоимостью каждого товара.

Как можно сохранить множество записей, возвращаемых селект и потом оперировать каждой из них в цикле?
Даже если реализовать можно более эффективно (без считывания и сохранения), всё равно хочется узнать, как можно сохранить несколько записей выборки и после оперировать ими?

Comment: Покажите, что уже пытались делать.

Comment: Интересно, кто вопрос закрыть пытается, вопрос абсолютно оправданный. Особенно с точки зрения Oracle, в котором есть готовые средства для хранения множеств. И при этом эти средства уникальны среди реляционных баз

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения такой задачи надо создать в процедуре Тип-коллекцию с полями соответствующими таблице (самое простое - использовать Имя_таблицы%ROWTYPE). 
Объявить переменную этого типа. И выбрать требуемые записи конструкцией `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

```
PROCEDURE process_all_rows
IS
   TYPE table_type
   IS TABLE OF MyTable%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   rows table_type;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO rows
     FROM MyTable;

   FOR indx IN 1 .. rows.COUNT 
   LOOP
      ... Используем в операциях поля вида rows(indx).имя_колонки
   END LOOP;
END process_all_rows;
```